# Why are Kidneys כְלָי֗וֹת Klayot in Tehillim 7:10 associated with Counsel?

Tags: commentaries, tehilim-psalms

While reading commentary from the Schottenstein Edition (ArtScroll Series) of **Tehillim 7:10** regarding כְלָי֗וֹת Klayot, you will find the statement:

> The kidneys are the seat of human counsel.

**Why are "Kidneys" כְלָי֗וֹת Klayot associated with human Counsel?**